# How to refer to a specific place of an HTML page?

Tags: html, hyperlink, reference

Is there such a mechanism in HTML that would allow me to make a hyperlink refer to a certain place in a page, rather than to it's beginning?

I mean, for example, I have a page with some text, and in that text there is such phrase: "I like cats". The URL of that page is

http://www.cats.com/bingo.html

So, when I refer to that page from another page I use a hyperlink similar to this

`[url="http://www.cats.com/bingo.html"]My attitude toward cats[/url]`

but this will get me to the very top of the page I am referring to. How can I make the hyperlink to open that page and scroll down to "I like cats" in the text? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can link to a part of the text by using hash-tags and id's

example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a large piece of text ...</p>
    <p>Another piece of text with <span id="cats">i like cats</span> in it.
</body>
<html>
```

if you now use the link http://www.cats.com/bingo.html#cats it will jump to that part

Comment: does it really work with an ID in any span or div? have never heard of it.

Comment: @Sascha — Yes, it does. You have to go back to Netscape 4 to find a browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: @Hierow - Thanks for your answer. Just a small follow-up question: What if I am referring to a page, which was not written by me, that is I have no access to that page's source. Can it still be done somehow?

Comment: @brilliant No, not that I know off. But if it's always the same page, you could check if there are nearby id's and link to that.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it like this way

for ex. page name was mypage.html

```
<a href="#link1">My link1</a>
```

after some another description or any content

and the place where you can jump set header like

My link1

when you click on My link1 then it will find the id and go to that position where the id was define in any tag like this way you can set for different also like

```
<a href="mypage2.html#link1">another page link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a small follow-up question: What if I am referring to a page, which was not written by me, that is I have no access to that page's source. Can it still be done somehow?